# Angular 2: How to add without loading page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-services

After clicking a button that calls the add function below, the data is being added into the database but not on the frontend itself. How do you add it without loading the page?

```js
addSection(section: Section) {
    section.name = section.name.trim();
    if(section.name != ''){
        this.onToggleDialogBox();
        this.sectionService
            .registerSection(section)
            .subscribe(
                res => alert(res.message),
                error => console.log(error)
        )
    }else{
        alert('Enter name.');
    }
}
```

If I use Router, here are the necessary codes:

```js
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private sectionService: SectionService
    ) {}

this.router.navigate(['/information/sections']);
```

Comment: In `res` of  `subscribe` function you have to do it manually what ever the changes you want.

Comment: The link is not found @RahulSingh

Comment: Yes. It says "Page not found" @RahulSingh

Comment: @Char i guess you pasted it you need not paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `subscription` of rxjs. After executing the method in service, append `.finally`. In your component, subscribe to that method with the subscription. So that if that method is executed, it will reflect on the component without loading the page

Answer (score 1):

Have two methods, one to add section to the server and another to add section to your front-end.  Once the section has been successfully added to the server, add it to the front-end as well.

```
addSectionToFront(section){ /* TODO: add to front-end */}

addSection(section){
  ...
  this.sectionService.register(section).subscribe(
    // server call succeeded. Now add section locally
    () => this.addSectionToFront(section),
    error => {}
  );
}
```